# What is my issue? Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I keep getting the error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' BUY0' to data type int, I am unsure what the issue with my code is. the column type for cd_tp_1_item_no is varchar(30)

```
$customers = array("4470","3650","4322");

foreach($customers as $customer){

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cd_tp_1_item_no FROM oeprcfil_sql where cd_tp_1_cust_no = $customer";
$result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$item[] = "";
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

             $item = $row['cd_tp_1_item_no'];

    }


}
```

Comment: The error is because you are using an integer value so there is an implicit conversion happening and you have at least one value in that column that is not an integer. You need to parameterize this query anyway which would help prevent sql injection and fix the current issue.

Comment: Oh I see adding a parenthesis and quotes ('$customer') fixed the issue, Also removing the brackets from $item[](this caused a different issue). Thanks for helping a newb!

Comment: That fixed the issue but did NOT fix the sql injection vulnerability. Please fix this before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: i will be sure to use a prepared statement before going live. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next suggestion to fix your issue:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cd_tp_1_item_no FROM oeprcfil_sql where cd_tp_1_cust_no = '".(int)$customer."'";
```